# Relación entre modelos Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

Soy nuevo en Laravel y estoy tratando de realizar un login pero mi estructura de tablas es la siguiente:

Tabla **Usuarios**:
Campos: usercod,userpass,usertip,usercreate,userideper

Tabla **personas**
Campos: userideper,userdoc,usernom,userape,userema,userdir

Mi login consiste en que la persona se pueda autenticar ya sea por su correo electrónico o su documento de identidad.

Estuve investigando y lo que eh intentado es lo siguiente:

Modelo **User**:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $guard        = 'users';
    protected $table        = 'Usuarios';
    protected $primaryKey   = 'usercod';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'usernom', 'userema', 'userpass','userideper',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function personas(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Persona');
    }

}
```

Modelo **Persona**:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Persona extends Model
{

}
```

Y por ultimo esto es lo que hago en mi controlador:

Controlador **AccessController**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;
use Hash;
use Redirect;
use Session;
use Validator;

class AccessController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
         return view('dashboard.login.access');
    }

    public function login(Request $request) {

        $datos = [
            'userema'   => $request->user_login,
            'userpass'     => $request->password
        ];
        if (Auth::guard()->attempt($datos)){
            session ( [
                    'name' => $request->get ( 'usernom' )
            ] );
            return Redirect::back ();
        } else {
            Session::flash ( 'message', "Invalid Credentials , Please try again." );
            return Redirect::back ();
        }
    }
    public function register(Request $request) {
        $rules = array (
                'email' => 'required|unique:users|email',
                'name' => 'required|unique:users|alpha_num|min:4',
                'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed'
        );
        $validator = Validator::make ( Input::all (), $rules );
        if ($validator->fails ()) {
            return Redirect::back ()->withErrors ( $validator, 'register' )->withInput ();
        } else {
            $user = new User ();
            $user->name = $request->get ( 'name' );
            $user->email = $request->get ( 'email' );
            $user->password = Hash::make ( $request->get ( 'password' ) );
            $user->remember_token = $request->get ( '_token' );
            $user->save ();
            return Redirect::back ();
        }
    }
    public function logout() {
        Session::flush ();
        Auth::logout ();
        return Redirect::back ();
    }
}
```

Y este es el error que me sale :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error ps es evidente ya que el campo no existe y por eso quiero hacer la relación, espero alguien me pueda ayudar y dar claridad sobre el tema.

Comment: No entiendo bien el problema. Si nos fijamos en el error, la solución estaría en modificar (y ejecutar) las migraciones, pero dices que eso lo tienes claro.... ¿entonces cuál es el error o problema real?

Comment: @Shaz En pocas palabras lo que me gustaria hacer es esto SELECT * FROM Usuarios u JOIN Personas p ON u.userideper = p.userideper WHERE (p.usermail = 'example@....' OR p.userdoc = 'example@...') AND u.userpass= 'asd'; Pero con Los modelos, no se si es posible hacerlo. Por eso ponia en el titulo, relación entre modelos.

Comment: el error muestra es que `userema` no existe en la base de datos, abre tu db y verifica que el campo existe en la tabla Usuarios

Comment: @marcogomes el campo existe en la tabla persona mas no en la tabla usuarios, por eso pregunto sobre si los modelos se pueden relacionar

Comment: ..como vas hacer una relacion con un campo que no existe ?...lo puedes relacion pero el campo tiene que existe..usa un campo de la tabla o crea uno.

Comment: @marcogomes el campo con el que yo quiero hacer la relación es userideper que se encuentra tanto en la tabla usuarios como en la tabla personas, siendo sentencia sql seria así: SELECT * FROM Usuarios u JOIN Personas p ON u.userideper = p.userideper WHERE (p.usermail = 'example@....' OR p.userdoc = 'example@...') AND u.userpass= 'asd'; eso es lo que quiero lograr, estoy mirando la documentación de laravel sobre eloquent-relationships pero sigo los pasos y no me sale.